Need to convert a layer of QGIS line intersections into nodes
In order to use the GAMA ABM software's driving skill functionality, I need to import a file of line segments containing the roads and a file of nodes containing the road intersections.
I want to use OSM via QGIS to create the files. The road file is fine. However I am having problems with the corresponding node file. If I create a layer comprising Highway = 'traffic_signals' or 'crossing' or 'stop', then I get a file of nodes but a large number of road intersections are missing.
If I create a file of line intersections (for example, vector dissolve 'road' layer / 'multipart to single parts' / 'line intersections' / 'delete duplicate geometries') I get a layer that looks correct - the nodes sit on the intersections as required.
However looking at the file attributes each 'point' is described as osm_type = 'way' rather than osm_type = 'node' as required.
Any suggestions as to how I might convert the points?

Nodes in graph theory https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory have a different meaning than in OSM. Points at the line intersections are the nodes what you need. The osm_type is irrelevant. The graph needs to know also the start and end points of each edge but perhaps the GAMA software can build the graph from valid line and point data.

To produce a file from QGIS of line intersections that comprises nodes (or points) then :

Create a road layer, using the 'highway'attribute.
Highlight the road layer then click  'Multipart to single', found in the processing toolbox.
Take the layer produced from 2., highlight it and then click 'Line intersections' also found in the processing toolbox.

Exporting this final layer to a shapefile gives a file of the road intersections in point/node form, as required.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
